# How to find system type using Python?

Tags: python

How can we find the system type (i.e. 32-bit or 64-bit) using Python...?

Comment: Do you mean the bitness of the OS or the Python interpreter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

32-bit versions of Python (no matter the architecture on which it is installed):

```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.architecture()
('32bit', 'WindowsPE')
```

64-bit versions of Python:

```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.architecture()
('64bit', 'WindowsPE')
```

Answer (score 3):

The `platform` module provides such information.  Example:

```
>>> platform.architecture()
('32bit', 'ELF')
```

More architecture-related information is available in `sys.platform` and `sys.byteorder`.

Comment: Its showing me (32-bit, WindowsPE) when infact I am running a 64-bit Windows OS...

Comment: the interpreter is a 32bit binary then.

Comment: @ParagSaoji: But obviously you are running a 32-bit Python interpreter.

Comment: @ParagSaoji: Try `platform.win32_ver()` to get information on the Windows version.

Answer (score 2):

see the platform module.

http://docs.python.org/library/platform.html

Comment: Its showing me (32-bit, WindowsPE) when infact I am running a 64-bit Windows OS...

Comment: @ParagSaoji But are you running a 64-bit version of python?